# Symfony2 how to filter query

Tags: symfony

**UPDATE**

Think I may have gone off course here, but I still get the same result with the whole page being displayed in the table.

So I am doing this for both the view and status pages.  View is the default page which shows all active alerts.  Status is the page that will display the filtered alerts.  So each of these pages has a controller

```
public function viewAction()
{
    $repository = $this
        ->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:Alert');

    $alerts = $repository->getAllActiveAlerts();

    return $this->render('NickAlertBundle:Page:view.html.twig', array(
        'alerts' => $alerts,
    ));
}

public function getActivatedAction(Request $request)
{
    $alertStatus = $request->request->get('status', 'active');
    $alerts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:Alert')->getAlertByStatus($alertStatus);

    return $this->render('NickAlertBundle:Page:status.html.twig', array("alerts"=>$alerts));
}
```

Each of these pages then has a route

```
NickAlertBundle_view:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:view }
    requirements:
       _method:  GET

NickAlertBundle_status:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:getActivated }
    requirements:
       _method:  POST
```

NickAlertBundle_view calls the view action and renders the page with all active alerts. NickAlertBundle_status calls the getActivated action.

Both of these views are the same, their content is as follows

```
{% extends 'NickAlertBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}

    <div class="col-md-12">

<section class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">View Alerts</h3>
        <select name="alerts" id="alerts" data-url="{{ path('NickAlertBundle_status') }}">
            <option value="active">Active</option>
            <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row" id="alert-container">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="datatable" class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Search Command</th>
                    <th>Flight Number</th>
                    <th>Booking Class</th>
                    <th>Alert Pseudo</th>
                    <th>Alert Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for alert in alerts %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ alert[0].id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert[0].searchCommand }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert.flight_number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert.classes }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert.pseudos }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert[0].alertStatus }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

So the data url should call the status route.  Both of the views have this because they should always be able to change the select on either page.

And then the javascript is pretty much the same as you have shown me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$('#alert-container table tbody').html(data);` line will set the contento of your tbody table from the response that the server return, so you have to have two different files

```
{% NickAlertBundle:Page:view.html.twig %}
{% extends 'NickAlertBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}

    <div class="col-md-12">

<section class="panel panel-default">
    <header class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">View Alerts</h3>
        <select name="alerts" id="alerts" data-url="{{ path('NickAlertBundle_status') }}">
            <option value="active">Active</option>
            <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
        </select>
    </header>
    <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="row" id="alert-container">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="datatable" class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Search Command</th>
                    <th>Flight Number</th>
                    <th>Booking Class</th>
                    <th>Alert Pseudo</th>
                    <th>Alert Status</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for alert in alerts %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ alert[0].id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert[0].searchCommand }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert.flight_number }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert.classes }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert.pseudos }}</td>
                            <td>{{ alert[0].alertStatus }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

and

```
{# NickAlertBundle:Page:status.html.twig #}
{% for alert in alerts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ alert[0].id }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert[0].searchCommand }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert.flight_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert.classes }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert.pseudos }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert[0].alertStatus }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Its actually really interesting.  I was still having the same problem after this change as well.  I then for some reason decided to change the pattern in the route file because it was the same as the show alert one.  And when I changed this pattern, it all works fine.  Dont know how, and not too sure why it doesnt actually change the url when I switch things over but hey, it works.  Thanks for all the help you have provided.

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to ask if you need something!

Comment: I am interested to know why using the same pattern in the two routes would cause this problem?  Do you know any reason why this was the case?

Comment: because the right form for declearing a route with a method is:
contact:
    pattern:     /contact
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:contact }
    methods:  [GET]

Answer (score 2):

---

UPDATED

---

The problem is basicaly that you are embedding the html response from viewAction when you actually have to put the code for the alerts, for example:

```
public function getActivatedAction(Request $request)
{
    $alertStatus = $request->request->get('status', 'active');
    $alerts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('NickAlertBundle:Alert')->findAllByStatus($alertStatus);

    return $this->render('NickAlertBundle:Alerts:show.html.twig', array("alerts"=>$alerts));
}
```

on the `NickAlertBundle:Alerts:show.html.twig`

```
{# NickAlertBundle:Alerts:show.html.twig #}
{% for alert in alerts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ alert[0].id }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert[0].searchCommand }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert.flight_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert.classes }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert.pseudos }}</td>
        <td>{{ alert[0].alertStatus }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

So then in your `NickAlertBundle:Page:view.html.twig` :

```
$('#alerts').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('#alerts').attr('data-url'), # getActivatedAction route
        data:{ status: $(this).val() },
        success: function(data){
            $('#alert-container table tbody').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

---

---

You can add a methond in your Enity Repository File:

```
# src/Package/AppBundle/Entity/AlertRepository.php
<?php

namespace Package\AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * AlertRepository
 *
 * This class was generated by the Doctrine ORM. Add your own custom
 * repository methods below.
 */
class AlertRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  public function findAllByStatus($status = "active")
  {
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $query = $qb
        ->where(
          $qb->expr()->eq('a.alertStatus', $status)
        )
        ->orderBy('a.id', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();
    return $query->getResult();
  }

}
```

and then in your controller, you can pass a json with the data or html:

```
<?php
...
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
...

public function getActivatedAction(Request $request)
{
    $alertStatus = $request->request->get('status', 'active');
    $alerts = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Alert')->findAllByStatus($alertStatus);

    // With JSON
    $json = alerts->toJson() // your own method

    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setData($json);

    // With HTML
    return $this->render('AppBundle:Alerts:show.html.twig', array("alerts"=>$alerts));
}
```

Now in yor html file you can use ajax to request the alerts:

```
<select name="alerts" id="alerts">
  <option value="active">Actives</option>
  <option value="inactive">Inactive</option>
</select>
<div id="alertsList"></div>

<script>
  $('#alerts').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "{{ path('alerts_getActivated') }}",
      data:{ status: $(this).val() },
      success: function(data){
          $('#alertsList').html(data); //Using the html response. With json you have to create the style and html here
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

If I didn't miss anything it should work.

If I get you wrong, please let me know, and I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for this fantastic explanation.  I have taken your comments on board but just have one small problem.  I have updated my question so you can see.  Thanks

Comment: For some reason it is the same as before.  It seems to grab all the HTML from the page and place it within my table.  How do I get data to only be the code I need?  Thanks

Comment: did you change the data-url attr from the select?? you have to point it to the new action "getActivatedAction", that will return only the tr content for each alert (NickAlertBundle:Alerts:show.html.twig)

Comment: remember, now you have 2 views, one with the full html code (NickAlertBundle:Page:view.html.twig) and the other with the tr structure (NickAlertBundle:Alerts:show.html.twig) and so, two actions, viewAction and getActivatedAction, with differents urls

Comment: I was trying to work out if there were different views.  Let me put all this together now and I will see if I can get it working.  Thanks

Comment: Question been updated again, seem to have got a bit lost

Answer (score 0):

To solve the url problem you should put:

```
NickAlertBundle_view:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:view }
    methods:  [GET]

NickAlertBundle_status:
    pattern:  /view-alerts
    defaults: { _controller: NickAlertBundle:Alert:getActivated }
    methods:  [POST]
```